# Bigquery - integer to timestamp

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery

I have an integer `20160115201307` and I want to convert it as the timestamp `2016-01-15 20:13:07` UTC. I have tried timestamp(date) but it gave wrong date as `1970-08-22 08:01:55` UTC. Anyone suggest which query I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

That is more likely a string not an integer, and you need to use regular expression to parse the string into components.

```
SELECT ds, 
   TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE(ds, r'(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)', r'\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6')) ts
FROM (SELECT '20160115201307 ' ds)
```

returns

```
+-----+----------------+-------------------------+--+
| Row | ds             | ts                      |  |
+-----+----------------+-------------------------+--+
| 1   | 20160115201307 | 2016-01-15 20:13:07 UTC |  |
+-----+----------------+-------------------------+--+
```

Comment: I have 900 records in a table.how to apply this for all records?

Comment: You can run a query that does the transformation and write it back to the same table, you can see under the options in the BQ WebUI that you can specify the same tables destination. Make sure you include all your columns you need.

Comment: So,do i need to perform this query for 900 times?

Comment: No, the purpose of SQL language is to write the query that does that. You need to adapt the solution which we showed you to run it on your schema.

Comment: i am attaching screenshot for this issue.prntscr.com/cfwbkz

Answer (score 1):

With standard SQL:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', CAST(20160115201307 AS STRING))
```

With 900 records in a table:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', CAST(col AS STRING))
FROM `dataset.table`
```

To enable standard SQL:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: Thanks for the help!!But I am getting the error "Failed to Parse string "0"" when i run query...

Comment: I have some timestamp fields named as 0 in some records.

Comment: Does a value of 0 mean `NULL`? In the cast you could instead do `CAST(IF(col = 0, NULL, col) AS STRING)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(CAST(timestamp_column AS INT64)/1000000 AS INT64)) AS converted
FROM [table] 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).